# Looking for PrtScrn button on Apple keyboard when RDPing to Windows

Tags: windows-10, macos, remote-desktop, print-screen

I am in macOS, using an Apple Magic Keyboard, and am RDPing to a Windows machine.  Is there a native key or key combo on the Mac side that will send the <kbd>PrtScrn</kbd> button press to Windows?  Looking at several standard keyboard layouts, it appears that PrtScrn usually sits in the position of <kbd>F13</kbd> on this keyboard, but neither that nor <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F13</kbd> achieved the desired result.

I understand how to screen cap in macOS, and how to screen cap in Windows, even through RDP, but I'm looking for the PrtScrn button itself.

Comment: Apple doesn't have or use a PrtScrn button. It's a function that has never been in macOS ever. I've always found with Win RDP that unless the client has a method to send this type of 'extra' data, you cannot do it from the keyboard alone.

Comment: You can use the on screen keyboard on the Windows side, or use the Windows snip tool to take screenshots.

Comment: @DavidPostill, I think you're onto the closest solution, the on-screen keyboard in Windows.  I mean, I know how to use the various snipping tools, on both sides, so that's not a problem.  It's the invocation by PrtScrn I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: you can also use Windows+Shift+S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I'm looking for the PrtScrn button itself.

Given that MAC keyboards don't have a <kbd>PrntScrn</kbd> key then you will have to use the on screen keyboard on the Windows side of the remote connection if you don't want to use the Snipping Tool.

I have done this when the remote session doesn't recognize the <kbd>PrntScrn</kbd> key on the local keyboard.

In this case I found it easier to [Use Snipping Tool to capture screenshots](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots-00246869-1843-655f-f220-97299b865f6b). This is a better workflow more me as I often need to copy just part of the screen and sometimes annotate the snip.